# What determines the limits for pasting a big query into psql?

Tags: postgresql, zsh, psql

On my local machine I have a handful of queries saved that I regularly update and then want to rerun on a remote production DB. Here's an example:

```
INSERT INTO exp_forum_member (forum_id, member_id)
SELECT 32, uid
FROM exp_members
WHERE email IN (
    'andrew@beaver.com',
    'charles@dragon.com',
    'edgar@frog.com'
)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

except that the real thing has a total of 134 lines and 3636 characters.

What I like to do is:

1. Open a local terminal session using `zsh` on my Mac
2. Connect to the remote database using `psql`
3. Paste in the query
4. Hit <kbd>return</kbd>

Sometimes this works but sometimes it doesn't. When it doesn't work, the pasted query appears on screen, and the prompt changes from `dbname=>` to `dbname(>`. Pressing <kbd>return</kbd> just starts a new line, with the same prompt.

Of course, I can get back to the regular prompt by pressing <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>. But the query never gets run.

What determines whether or not I can paste in my query? I assume the issue is related to a length constraint, or possibly the presence of certain whitespace characters. And is there any way to overcome these constraints? (I realize I could also run `psql -f` and point it to the local file, in this instance. But that is more complicated and doesn't always work, for instance when running `psql` in a remote session.)

Comment: You are pasting into your terminal, so it might be a limitation of the local terminal that it pastes incorrectly? The `dbname(>` suggests that you have an open parantheses in your SQL suggesting further that a line was missed in the paste. Perhaps you would have better luck dropping the sql into an empty file and then using psql to run that files sql against the remote database.

Comment: Thanks @JNevill. 
_so it might be a limitation of the local terminal_
Yes, that certainly seems possible. The terminal is perfectly capable of having that same text pasted into it when, for example, editing a document in Vim, though, so I'm hoping someone can provide more detail.
_using psql to run that files sql against the remote database_
Yes, I did that ultimately and it worked fine. I'm just hoping to avoid that more complex workflow in future :-)